# Unity Asset Store Bundles and Git

Tags: git, unity-game-engine, version-control, git-submodules

I have recently got into Unity development and was wondering how the Unity asset store bundles work and what are they capable of. I am currently using 2 asset packs in my project that contain quite a few textures and meshes and other considerably big files to store on git repo.

My question is, what should I do with these asset packs. I can (almost certainly) just redownload them from asset store, so they don't really need to be saved in my git repo. However, I don't know if the unity package manager (if it even exists) is capable of somehow storing information of dependencies that should be downloaded from asset store if missing (f.e. fresh clone of my repo).

What I would like to achieve is something similar to git sobmodule or Swift's cocoapods just refering to external depenency that is not tracked directly in my repository.

P.S.: I would like to not use Git LFS because currently I have the repo saved on my faculty's gitlab server (which doesn't even have LFS support I think) and would be forced to migrate it to GitHub or smth.

Answer (score -1):

It’s unnecessary to manage the packages in your git repo for unity project.

As you found, when you want to import packages into your project, you can get from external directories.

And if you want to manage the packages, you can create another git repo to manage the packages.

To manage the package repo as submodule for your project repo or manage and package repo repo separately, you can decide for your own preference.

Comment: I don't really understand the second sentence. I know that I shouldn't include packages in my repository, but if I just add them to `.gitignore` how will Unity know to download them on fresh clone when they are not there?

Comment: Add the packages in `.gitignore` of the project git repo does not affect you to download (select manually) or fresh clone (execute `git pull` manually in the local package repo). And if you want to update the imported packages automatically, of cause, you can add the package repo as the submodule of your project repo.

Comment: How did you manage the package repo now, submodule for project repo or manage separately? And do you successful manage them now?

Comment: Previously I simply downloaded one version of the unity store package and then tracked it whole in my project. Now I need to add much bigger package, which I don't want to keep copy of in my repository. In the end I've decided to copy the package, delete not relevant files and save big files with Git LFS.

Comment: So you manage the packages in your project repo with git LFS? Did you try to treat the package repo as a submodule of your project repo or manage the package repo outside of your project repo?